# How select data from distinct Companies in the same row?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

Is it possible to select distinct company names from the customer table but also displaying the iD's related?

at the minute I'm using

```
SELECT company,id, COUNT(*) as count FROM customers GROUP BY company HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

which returns

```
MyDuplicateCompany1 64  2
MyDuplicateCompany2 20  3
MyDuplicateCompany6 175 2
```

but what I'm after is all the duplicate ID's for each.

so

```
CompanyName, TimesDuplicated, DuplicateId1, DuplicateId2, DuplicateId3
```

or a row for each so

```
MyDuplicateCompany1, DuplicateId1, TimesDuplicated
MyDuplicateCompany1, DuplicateId2, TimesDuplicated
MyDuplicateCompany2, DuplicateId1, TimesDuplicated
MyDuplicateCompany2, DuplicateId2, TimesDuplicated
MyDuplicateCompany2, DuplicateId3, TimesDuplicated
```

is this possible?

Comment: use `group_concat(ID) as CompanyIDsList`  to generate a list like (DuplicateID1, DuplicateID2)

Comment: How does `id` relate to `DuplicateId1`?

Comment: Will you please clarify your question? Are you trying to find the number of duplicated customer IDs within a company? Or are you trying to find the number of duplicated companies?

Comment: @Noah I'd guess Duplicate Names.  Since the count has 2 for MyDuplicateComapny1 and he's looking for different ID's  Plus in a RDBMS who would ever let an "ID" field be duplicated from a unique record standpoint; however those are assumptions so the question is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT(id)` to concat your id by comma, your query should be:

```
SELECT company, GROUP_CONCAT(id) as ids, COUNT(id) as cant FROM customers GROUP BY company HAVING cant > 1
```

You can test  the query with this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `company` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `customers` (`id`, `company`) VALUES
(1, 'MyDuplicateCompany1'),
(2, 'MyDuplicateCompany1'),
(3, 'MyDuplicateCompany1'),
(4, 'MyDuplicateCompany2'),
(5, 'MyDuplicateCompany2'),
(6, 'MyDuplicateCompany3'),
(7, 'MyDuplicateCompany3'),
(8, 'MyDuplicateCompany3'),
(9, 'MyDuplicateCompany3'),
(10, 'MyDuplicateCompany4');
```

Output:

[image]

Read more at:
http://monksealsoftware.com/mysql-group_concat-and-postgres-array_agg/

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this would be acceptable but there's a function in mySQL which allows you to combine multiple rows into one [Group_Concat(Field)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), but show the distinct values for each record for columns specified (like ID in this case)

```
SELECT company
      , COUNT(*) as count
      , group_concat(ID) as DupCompanyIDs 
FROM customers 
GROUP BY company 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ed10b/1/0)
 showing similar results with duplicate companies listed in one field.

If you need it in multiple columns or multiple rows, you could wrap the above as an inline view and inner join it back to customers on the name to list the duplicates and times duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

You are not looking for companies with more than 1 entry (`GROUP BY company`), but for duplicate company IDs (`GROUP BY company, id`):

```
SELECT company, id, COUNT(*)
FROM customers 
GROUP BY company, id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Again, grouping by auto_increment ID + anything would give you a count(*) of 1 all the time.

Comment: @ebyrob: If ID were the tables unique ID, as its name admittedly suggests, then you'd be right, but then the whole question would not make sense anymore. So far we see a result row per company along with its record count and an arbitrary ID. But the OP wants to see *duplicate* IDs for a company. Look at the desired output. So obviously the OP thinks there *can* be duplicate IDs. My query finds those. You may notice that *all* of us read the question the same way except yourself. If it was you who downvoted my answer, please think that over.

Comment: I agree, though, that ID is a horrible column name for this case and should better be customer_number or something along these lines. The name ID suggests to be the table's unique ID, which is obviously not to the case here.

Comment: The OP is looking for the same company showing up for more than one ID (ie: row) in the customer table.  Seems to make sense to me even if `id` is the auto increment ID.

Comment: @ebyrob: Again, look at the desired output. You see MyDuplicateCompany1 twice, once with DuplicateId1 and once with DuplicateId2. Also there are three records for MyDuplicateCompany2. The OP says "but what I'm after is all the duplicate ID's for each" [company obviously].

Comment: It sounds to me like you're making my point for me.  `GROUP BY company,id` isn't going to uncover duplicates in only one or the other.  For that you'd need to choose only one column.  COUNT(*) will always be 1 for the example data set.

Comment: @ebyrob: No, if there are four records, company1-id1, company1-id1, company1-id2, company2-id1, then my query finds company1-id1 with a count of 2, because that ID (or customer number) is used twice for the same company. But well, let's just wait for the OP to clear things up.

Comment: We must be looking at different questions.  I see comp1-id1 duplicated no where in the question.  If I stretch it, there is comp1-id1, comp2-id1, but certainly no instance of c1-i1 showing up twice.

Answer (score 0):

This should give exactly what you're looking for without `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
SELECT
  company, id,
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) from customers AS b
    WHERE a.company = b.company
  ) AS cnt
FROM customers AS a
GROUP BY company, id
HAVING cnt > 1
;
```

Note: `GROUP_CONCAT` does the same thing, just all in one row per company.